# right justify number fields within Java JTable abstract model

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Does anybody know how to centre data within a `JTableabstract` data model.

The default seems to be to right justify.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you cannot change from the table model, it is controlled from the cell renderers.

Take a look at this example taken from [Code Ranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/339108/GUI/java/right-justify-text-JTable):

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.table.*;  

public class AlignRight  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        String[] headers = { "column 1", "column 2", "column 3", "column 4" };  
       int cols = 4;  
       int rows = 6;  
       String[][] data = new String[rows][cols];  
       for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)  
           for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)  
               data[row][col] = "item " + (row * cols + col + 1);  
       JTable table = new JTable(data, headers);  
       DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =  
               (DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class);  
       renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);  
       JFrame f = new JFrame();  
       f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
       f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));  
       f.setSize(400,400);  
       f.setLocation(200,200);  
       f.setVisible(true);  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks okay will figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "abstract data model", you're referring to the AbstractTableModel class.  This is actually not the correct place to handle justification.  The table model represents the "model" behind the table.  What you want to do is modify the way this model is displayed to screen(the "view").

The appropriate way to do this is to create a custom render for the JTable.  In your case, you can extend the DefaultTableCellRenderer class and override getTableCellRenderer to set the horizontal alignment of the returned component.  For more information on custom renderers - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer